ColorPicker with empty label: horizontal alignment issue
The source of my problem I ran into (and only diagnosed due to the XCode "Debug View Hierarchy" tool) was being required to put an empty "" string for the native SwiftUI ColorPicker.
The problem itself is that this empty label actually takes up space in my view, thus stopping me from simply aligning my ColorPickers as such:
private var customColorPickers: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 10) {
        Spacer()
        ForEach(0..<(colorPalettes.last?.count ?? 0), id: \.self) { customIndex in
            customColorPicker(index: customIndex)
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .frame(alignment: .center)
}

For context, this is my customColorPicker definition:
private func customColorPicker(index: Int) -> some View {
    ColorPicker("",
        selection: Binding(
            get: {
                colorPalettes[3][index]
            },
            set: { newColor in
                
                colorPalettes[3][index] = newColor
                
                if (index == 0) {
                    widgetCustomColorPaletteFirstIndex = newColor.hex
                } else if (index == 1) {
                    widgetCustomColorPaletteSecondIndex = newColor.hex
                } else if (index == 2) {
                    widgetCustomColorPaletteThirdIndex = newColor.hex
                } else {
                    // do nothing, idk
                }
                sharedVars.colorPaletteIndex = 3
                widgetColorPaletteIndex = 3
                WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "QuoteDropletWidget")
            }
        ),
        supportsOpacity: true
    )
    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
    .cornerRadius(8)
    .onChange(of: colorPalettes) { _ in
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadTimelines(ofKind: "QuoteDropletWidget")
    }
}

You can see the empty view space below from the view hierarchy debugging tool (circled in red):


The solution I found was—full credit to this GitHub Gist user—from this code snippet he posted here (my implementation using his struct below):
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
public struct ColorPickerWithoutLabel: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var selection: Color
    var supportsAlpha: Bool = true
    
    public init(selection: Binding<Color>, supportsAlpha: Bool = true) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.supportsAlpha = supportsAlpha
    }
    
    
    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIColorWell {
        let well = UIColorWell()
        well.supportsAlpha = supportsAlpha
        return well
    }
    
    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIColorWell, context: Context) {
        uiView.selectedColor = UIColor(selection)
    }
}

My Code Before:
ColorPicker("",
        selection: Binding(
            get: {
                // irrelevant logic for Stackoverflow answer
            },
            set: { // irrelevant logic for Stackoverflow answer
            }
        ),
        supportsOpacity: true
    )
    // irrelevant modifiers for Stackoverflow answer

My Code After (implementing this ColorPickerWithoutLabel):
ColorPickerWithoutLabel(
        selection: Binding(
            get: {
                // irrelevant logic for Stackoverflow answer
            },
            set: { // irrelevant logic for Stackoverflow answer
            }
        ),
        supportsAlpha: true
    )
    // irrelevant modifiers for Stackoverflow answer

As you can tell, the only changes were to use ColorPickerWithoutLabel, instead of ColorPicker, of course + changing supportsOpacity to supportsAlpha + removing the empty label argument ("").
After this change, you can see in the View Hierarchy Debug tool that this view space is no longer being taken up by an empty label:



Note that CG Colors don't seem to work well with the ColorPickerWithoutLabel -> If you have a similar case to me, where the only issue with the native ColorPicker is the padding being too far to the right, you can simply add a padding(.trailing, 30) to the right-most (or only) color picker, where 30 is half of your frame size (mine is 60).

